# Migrating FB open graph actions, objects and aggregations from dev to production app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Been hacking facebook open graph to publish items to a users stream, currently I have created all of the actions/objects/aggregations using a test app.  I will however wish to

a)  Migrate this to our staging server to test
b)  Once a) completed migrate this to the production server

Given each FB app has its own domain (and my staging/prod have their own domains) - I have a app for each environment.  I would prefer not however to be re-creating the actions/objects/aggregations on both the staging and prod version of the apps.  Does anyone know of a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create subdomains of your main domain? If so, apps will work across multiple subdomains (this can be setup in your [Developer Settings Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)). Alternatively, you can perform the main authentication and permissions step on your production domain and then redirect to your staging domain, using the same access tokens (most API calls aren't restricted to the app domain by default).

Comment: What about the callback url, the "Site URL" in the app settings? It does not fit if the subdomain is different.